# rJava print into R console

Tags: java, r, printing, io, rjava

I've been using rJava package to call java codes from within R recently. I use linux most of the time and run R from terminal. I did not realize there is a huge I/O problem until I recently wrote a package using rJava. I want to know if anyone could help me with it.

The idea was to run a MCMC sampler using Java so it's much faster. I want to print out progress message every k-th iteration. In Java, I use System.out.printf(). It works fine when running R in terminal, but it's totally not working when running R GUI or Rstudio. Here is the list of things I tried:

- In terminal the messages are printed as they are called.
- In mac Rstudio, the messages are printed as they are called.
- In mac R GUI, the messages are printed all together when the whole Java call is finished.
- In Windows, both R GUI and Rstudio, the messages totally disappear, not printed out at all...

I'm wondering if there's any easy way to work with the I/O stream in R? I know Rcpp has this nice Rprintf function that you could use to tap into R console. Does anyone know if I could do something similar in Java? Thanks.

***Update:***
To let people know what I did eventually: I was not able to find anything to get around the printing to console thing in all those cases, so for windows at least, I added another graphical interface in my java codes, i.e., creating a pop-up window with the messages I need, and a progress bar. Not ideal, as it makes my package running with different looks under different platforms, but better than nothing...Still happy to hear new thoughts on this.

Comment: Did you finally find a way to print to the console?

Comment: My 2 cents: start a Windows command prompt *(yes, the good old `cmd.exe`)*, start the R GUI **from** that command prompt, and check whether the Java output is dumped to the only "console" available i.e. the parent command prompt -- or not. I'm afraid it depends on the Windows edition -- seems to work in Windows 8 Home 64bit, in Windows Server 2012, but not on Windows 7 Pro 32bit (go figure...)